# Error when trying to validate iOS app: iPhone/ipod info.plist: Unable to verify icon dimensions, no Icon found. You must define CFBundleIcons

Tags: ios, xcode, validation

I know others have had this problem. I have tried everything, I think I am overlooking something simple. I can't post a screenshot of my info.plist file, but all of the icon files are capitalized and all the .png file names match what is in the icon files array in the -info.plist file. Can anyone help please?

[image: http://i45.tinypic.com/amb15i.png]

Comment: You can upload image to [any third party site](http://tinypic.com/) and post the link here.

Comment: http://i45.tinypic.com/amb15i.png

Comment: Are you sure all images are as per this [Apple doc on icons](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html) and [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW1)?

Comment: Select your target and view the Summary tab in Xcode. Do your icons appear properly on the Summary tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW1) on icon files and [this Mobile HIG on Icons](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html).

This is what mentioned in [this old link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1686/_index.html) from Apple:

[image]

So please correct all the icons and its names as per the documentation. Basically the 57x57 icon title will be `Icon.png` and for @2x, `Icon@2x.png`. For 72x72 icon, the title should be `Icon-72.png`. Similarly change the other titles as well.

Here is a [blog on the Icon name](http://pinchmultimedia.com/blog/ios-5-icon-sizes-and-names-new-ipad)s.

Comment: I appreciate everyone's suggestions. I have gone through all the documentation again, corrected icon names, reviewed the info.plist file to make sure everything is right. Still getting the same error message. The icon files are in my 'Supporting Files' folder in my Xcode project, is that where they should be?

Comment: Yes, that is fine. So the icon names are changed and also the icon resolutions are also checked?

Comment: OK, well I'm pretty embarrassed by this but after many hours of trying everything, I figured out my error...after fixing validation issues I was not creating a new archive. I was basically attempting to validate the same archive again. But in the process I learned a ton about submitting an app to the app store. My app is now submitted and waiting for review. Thank you again for your help!